# Xdebug won't run on local website in NetBeans

Tags: php, apache, netbeans, xampp, xdebug

I've created a PHP project in NetBeans called TerraNubis. The project folder and source folder are located in `C:\development\TerraNubis`. In the Project Properties window, in the Run Configuration tab I've set the option to run the configuration as local website, the project url to `http://localhost/TerraNubis/` and the index file to `index.php`.

I installed XAMPP (xampp-win32-7.1.11-0-VC14-installer.exe on Windows 10) and downloaded Xdebug (php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14.dll, which is now located in `C:\xampp\php\ext`).

The files from the sources folder are being copied to `C:\xampp\htdocs\TerraNubis`. In the NetBeans Options window I've set the PHP 5 interpreter to `C:\xampp\php\php.exe`. In the Debugging tab, the debugger port is set to 9000, the session ID to `netbeans-xdebug` and the maximum data length to 2048. All the checkboxes in this tab are empty.

In my php.ini file I commented out

```
zend.enable_gc = On
```

and at the bottom of the file I added the following code:

```
[XDEBUG]
zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.5-7.1-vc14.dll"
xdebug.idekey = netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:/xampp/tmp/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 0
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_host = "127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_log = "C:/xampp/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remot.log"
xdebug.show_local_vars = 9
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:/xampp/tmp"
```

In NetBeans, when I right click on the TerraNubis project in the Projects tree and click on Debug, I see at the bottom right the message: "Waiting For Connection (netbeans-xdebug)". Then nothing happens. It just keeps displaying the same message.

How can I run the Xdebug properly on a local website?

Comment: So ... 1) does Apache from XAMPP displays your website? In one place you have mentioned URL of `http://localhost:8000` .. and then mentioning changing the XAMPP's default web server port to `81` (because of Skype conflict). Don't see why it was needed to be mentioned here. BTW -- you could just tell Skype to not to use those ports -- as simple as that. 2) What's your xdebug log has to show -- does it even try to connect to NetBeans? P.S. Not a NetBeans user (using PhpStorm) .. so not sure if some steps are missing -- just checking for typical "xdebug side misconfiguration" bits.

Comment: I've changed the port options in Skype and I set the port options in the httpd.conf file back to their original states. I also changed the local host name to `http://localhost/TerraNubis/` and checked the box for copying the source folders to `C:\xampp\htdocs\TerraNubis`, see edited question

Comment: So ... what xdebug log has to say? If it shows nothing (e.g. no log file created) then debug was not even attempted .. or xdebug is not active. Can you confirm that `phpinfo()` shows xdebug active and all options were applied?

Comment: In the XAMPP Control Panel, when I click on Logs in the Apache row it doesn't display anything about Xdebug. The `phpinfo()` function shows this: 

`xdebug support enabled
Version  2.5.5
IDE Key  netbeans-xdebug
Supported protocols Revision
DBGp - Common DeBuGger Protocol  $Revision: 1.145 $
Directive Local Value Master Value
xdebug.auto_trace Off Off
xdebug.cli_color 0 0
xdebug.collect_assignments Off Off
xdebug.collect_includes On On
xdebug.collect_params 0 0
xdebug.collect_return Off Off
xdebug.collect_vars Off Off
xdebug.coverage_enable On On
xdebug.default_enable On On`